# Why Using addTrack instead of addTransceiver allows you to publish a stream

Tags: webrtc

#### Purpose

first, I create a local_pc RTCPeerConnection. then the local_pc want a video track from remote_pc. so I create a remote_pc and create a video track for remote_pc.
if I use `addTrack` instead of `addTransceiver` everything works well. But if I use `addTransceiver` instead of `addTrack`, it works bad

#### Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Ask then Publish</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
      let local_pc,
        remote_pc,
        localOffer,
        remoteAnswer,
        candidates = [];
      const createLocalPc = () => {
          local_pc = new RTCPeerConnection();
      };
      const createRemotePc = () => {
        remote_pc = new RTCPeerConnection();
      }

      const listenLocalPcEvents = () => {
        local_pc.ontrack = (event) => {
          console.log("localPc receive Track", event);
        };
        local_pc.onicecandidate = (event) => {
          const candidate = event.candidate;
          console.log("localPc gather candidate is", candidate);
          remote_pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
        };

        local_pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = (event) => {
          console.log("localPc ice-connection-state is", local_pc.iceConnectionState);
        };
      };

      const listenRemotePcEvents = () => {
        remote_pc.ontrack = (event) => {
          console.log("remotePc receive Track", event);
        };
        remote_pc.onicecandidate = (event) => {
          const candidate = event.candidate;
          console.log("remotePc gather candidate is", candidate);
          local_pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
        };

        remote_pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = (event) => {
          console.log("remotePc ice-connection-state is", local_pc.iceConnectionState);
        };
      };

      const createLocalPcTransceiver =  async () => {
        /*
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          video: true,
          audio: false
        });
        let videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
        local_pc.addTransceiver(videoTrack, {
          direction: "sendonly",
          streams: [stream]
        });
         */
        local_pc.addTransceiver("video", {
          direction: "sendrecv"
        });
      };

      const createRemotePcTransceiver = async () => {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          video: true,
          audio: false
        });
        let videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
        remote_pc.addTrack(videoTrack);
        // remote_pc.addTransceiver(videoTrack, {
        //   direction: "sendonly",
        // });
        /*
        remote_pc.addTransceiver("video", {
          direction: "recvonly"
        });
         */
      }

      const createLocalOffer = async () => {
        localOffer = await local_pc.createOffer();
        await local_pc.setLocalDescription(localOffer);
      };

      const createRemoteAnswer = async () => {
        remoteAnswer = await remote_pc.createAnswer();
        await remote_pc.setLocalDescription(remoteAnswer);
        await local_pc.setRemoteDescription(remoteAnswer);
      };



      const init = async () => {
        createLocalPc();
        listenLocalPcEvents();
        await createLocalPcTransceiver();
        await createLocalOffer();

        // await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 4000));

        createRemotePc();
        await remote_pc.setRemoteDescription(localOffer);
        listenRemotePcEvents();
        await createRemotePcTransceiver();
        await createRemoteAnswer();
      };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Expect

If I use `addTrack` then local_pc trigger ontrack events
If I use `addTransceiver` then local_pc will not trigger ontrack events
I think `addTransceiver` should work well too, is anything wrong with the code

Comment: I read some paper about `addTransceiver` from https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-rtcpeerconnection-addtransceiver.
It tells me that `addTransceiver` just affects `createOffer` and `addTrack` affects `createOffer` and `createAnswer`

Comment: So I replace one filed of answer's sdp  after `createAnswer`, just `remoteAnswer.sdp.replace("a=inactive", "a=sendonly");` It seems everything works well.